# connect accordian heading and body through href and id

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a bootstrap accordian. When i click an accordian heading, it should show the body contents. I am providing the values dynamically(scope variable) for href and id attributes using angularjs.
But this is not working??

```
            <div class="panel-group col-lg-3" style="background-color:#505054;height:450px" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel" style="background-color:#505054;color:#C1C1C1;border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;">
                    <h6>Clear Filter</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="panel" style="background-color:#505054;color:white;border-bottom: 1px solid white;" ng-repeat="prdlines in detpline">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h6>
                        <div class="accordion-toggle" style="cursor:pointer" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" ng-click="plfilter(prdlines.id)" ng-href="{{prdlines.productline_name}}">{{prdlines.productline_name}}</div>
                    </h6>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-attr-id="{{prdlines.productline_name}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul id="style-3" style="height:200px; overflow: auto;cursor:pointer">
                               <li class="panel-title" ng-repeat="prd in detprd"><a ng-click="cfilter(prd.product_name)"><h5>{{prd.product_name}}</h5></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

What is the syntax problem?

Comment: can you add plunkr?

Comment: @Manikandan i cant bcz i am using rest api which need credentials. I cant give credentials

Comment: You don't need to give credentials. You can create plunkr same as your task.

Comment: @Manikandan plunkr need credentials right? i have created plunker but angularjs is not loading. I am retrieving the data for accordian from angularjs rest api

Answer (score 0):

For accordian you don't need to specify href and id. Use UI bootstrap.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion

http://embed.plnkr.co/3y0Rq1/

Comment: you are using ui bootstrap.But i need it in bootstrap 3 and angularjs